# Scala Akka (un)marshalling nested Seq collections with Spray JSON

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm trying to use Spray JSON to marshall the 'Seq' collection below into a 'BidRequest' entity with the parameters as defined.
The Seq collection is mostly nested, therefore some 'Seq' parameter fields also have variable collection types that need to be marshalled.
Then after a computation, the aim is to unmarshall the results as an entity of 'BidResponse'.

What's the best approach to do this?

I'm using Akka-HTTP, Akka-Streams, Akka-Actor.

Seq collection:

```scala
      val activeUsers = Seq(
          Campaign(
              id = 1,
              country = "UK",
              targeting = Targeting(
                  targetedSiteIds = Seq("0006a522ce0f4bbbbaa6b3c38cafaa0f") 
                  ),
                  banners = List(
                      Banner(
                          id = 1,
                          src ="https://business.URLTV.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/openGraph.jpeg",
                          width = 300,
                          height = 250
                          )
                        ),
                  bid = 5d
                )
            )
```

BidRequest case class:

```scala
case class BidRequest(id: String, imp: Option[List[Impression]], site:Site, user: Option[User], device: Option[Device])
```

BidResponse case class:

```scala
case class BidResponse(id: String, bidRequestId: String, price: Double, adid:Option[String], banner: Option[Banner])
```

The other case classes:

```scala
case class Campaign(id: Int, country: String, targeting: Targeting, banners: List[Banner], bid: Double)
case class Targeting(targetedSiteIds: Seq[String])
case class Banner(id: Int, src: String, width: Int, height: Int)

case class Impression(id: String, wmin: Option[Int], wmax: Option[Int], w: Option[Int], hmin: Option[Int], hmax: Option[Int], h: Option[Int], bidFloor: Option[Double])
case class Site(id: Int, domain: String)
case class User(id: String, geo: Option[Geo])
case class Device(id: String, geo: Option[Geo])
case class Geo(country: Option[String])
```

I've so far tried using the code below but keep getting type mismatch errors:

```scala
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

implicit val resFormat = jsonFormat2(BidResponse)
implicit val bidFormat = jsonFormat1(BidRequest)
implicit val cFormat = jsonFormat1(Campaign)
implicit val tFormat = jsonFormat1(Targeting)
implicit val bFormat = jsonFormat1(Banner)
implicit val iFormat = jsonFormat1(Impression)
implicit val sFormat = jsonFormat1(Site)
implicit val uFormat = jsonFormat1(User)
implicit val dFormat = jsonFormat1(Device)
implicit val gFormat = jsonFormat1(Geo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting Type errors with Spray JSON is because you need to use the corresponding *jsonFormatN* method, depending on the number of parameters in the case class.

In your case:

```
implicit val resFormat = jsonFormat5(BidResponse)
implicit val bidFormat = jsonFormat5(BidRequest)
implicit val cFormat = jsonFormat1(Campaign)
implicit val tFormat = jsonFormat1(Targeting)
implicit val bFormat = jsonFormat4(Banner)
...
```